# Form content as a parameter for a query in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a noob dev trying to write a simple CRUD for a database in Cloud Firestore.

I have a form with text fields (showing just one to make his question simple to read)

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="authorName"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
<input type="text" name="authorName" id="authorName" placeholder="Author's name" />
</div>
```

After that, I wrote the code to retrieve from DB the info in the "texts" :

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", event => {
     db.collection("texts").where('authorName', '==', 'textAuthorName').get().then((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
         console.log(doc.data())
         renderLista(doc)
         });
     });
 });
```

And finally I wrote a line that capture what the user typed.

```
var authorName = document.querySelector("#authorName").value;
```

It doesn't work and the Firefox's web console remains blank.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work?? Can you help us showing what the error you are facing?

Comment: @Fire-In-D-Hole, that's the point: the console shows nothing :-(

Here's the link for the whole code (I'm brazilian, so the var's and id's are in portuguese):

[link] (https://newagent-48d6b.firebaseapp.com/consultar001.html)

Comment: Another strange thing: despite a firebase init and firebase deploy,the Functions section of the Firebase console don't have an function ... I am stuck :-(